# Finding all even factorizations of a given number n - javascript python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, number-theory, factorization

Currently i am implementing an algorithm that relies on finding all even factorizations of a given number n, including n.

I've tried some things, but overall i am not able to handle the problem well. Maybe its a good idea to handle it recursively, but i am not that good with javascript yet, especially with the higher level aspects of the language which might come in handy.

```
function evens(n) {
evens = []
for (var i = 2; i < n/2 - 1; i++){
    if (i % 2 != 0){
        continue;
    }
    else {
        if ((n/i) % 2 == 0) {
            evens.push([n/i, i])
        }
    }
}
return evens
}
```

This is some code that goes some of the way, but i am not yet able to recursively implement it considering all the right base cases.
I also thought that it could be done with a tree like structure in which paths are even factors, but my cs knowledge is pretty bad.

Suggestions in Python are also welcome, but javascript would be best.

Just to make everything more clear: all even factorizations of 136 for example are [[68, 2], [34, 2, 2], [34, 4], [136]].

Thankfull for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe its a good idea to handle it recursively

Here's my attempt at a recursive solution in Python:

```
def even_factorization(n):
    solutions = []

    def even_divisors(n):  # 136 generates [2, 4, 8, 34, 68, 136]
        return (d for d in range(2, n + 1, 2) if n % d == 0)

    def remove_similarities(array):  # [[2, 2, 34], [2, 34, 2], [34, 2, 2]] -> [[2, 2, 34]]
        return list(map(list, set(map(lambda a: tuple(sorted(a)), array))))

    for divisor in even_divisors(n):
        if divisor == n:
            solutions.append([divisor])
        else:
            for solution in even_factorization(n // divisor):
                solutions.append([divisor] + solution)

    return remove_similarities(solutions)  # return 'solutions' to see raw data
```

For 136 returns:

```
[[2, 2, 34], [4, 34], [2, 68], [136]]
```

for 218960 returns:

```
[[184, 1190], [8, 27370], [4, 54740], [2, 70, 1564], [56, 3910], [2, 2, 170, 322],
[280, 782], [70, 3128], [4, 46, 1190], [2, 2, 34, 1610], [2, 14, 34, 230],
[2, 14, 7820], [20, 34, 322], [10, 14, 34, 46], [14, 92, 170], [20, 46, 238],
[218960], [2, 322, 340], [10, 68, 322], [34, 46, 140], [10, 14, 1564],
[2, 10, 10948], [10, 92, 238], [4, 170, 322], [92, 2380], [14, 20, 782],
[10, 21896], [238, 920], [28, 34, 230], [10, 28, 782], [2, 2, 46, 1190],
[2, 28, 3910], [10, 34, 644], [34, 6440], [2, 92, 1190], [46, 4760], [2, 170, 644],
[2, 68, 1610], [4, 70, 782], [340, 644], [2, 34, 46, 70], [2, 20, 5474],
[14, 68, 230], [2, 34, 3220], [4, 34, 1610], [4, 10, 5474], [28, 7820],
[14, 34, 460], [322, 680], [10, 46, 476], [2, 2, 54740], [4, 230, 238],
[2, 2, 2, 27370], [34, 70, 92], [2, 140, 782], [14, 15640], [2, 10, 46, 238],
[2, 10, 14, 782], [2, 14, 46, 170], [2, 238, 460], [136, 1610], [2, 2, 10, 5474],
[20, 10948], [4, 14, 3910], [40, 5474], [2, 2, 70, 782], [2, 2, 230, 238],
[230, 952], [68, 3220], [2, 46, 2380], [2, 230, 476], [2, 10, 34, 322],
[140, 1564], [460, 476], [170, 1288], [2, 4, 27370], [46, 68, 70], [14, 46, 340],
[2, 109480], [28, 46, 170], [2, 2, 14, 3910]]
```

Comment: This is pretty much what i thought of, well done.
I have used your algorithm to save the even factorizations of about 2000 numbers to proceed with them, i might try to replicate the algorithm in javascript some time in the future.
Very pythonian :)

Answer (score 1):

After cdlane correctly pointed out a flaw in my solution, I have retracted my original solution, and ported cdlane's elegant python solution to javascript.

```
function even_factorization(n) {
  let solutions = [];

  function even_divisors(n) {
      var divisors = [];
      for (let i = 2; i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i === 0) divisors.push(i);
      }
      return divisors;
  }

  function remove_similarities(combos) {
    for (let i = 0; i < combos.length; i++) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < combos.length; j++) {
        if (combos[i].sort((a,b) => a - b).join(" ") === combos[j].sort((a,b) => a - b).join(" ")) {
          combos.splice(j--,1);
        }
      }
    }
    return combos;
  }

  even_divisors(n).forEach(divisor => {
    if (divisor === n)
      solutions.push([divisor]);
    else {
        even_factorization(n / divisor).forEach(solution => {
          solutions.push([divisor, ...solution]);
        });
    }
  });

  return remove_similarities(solutions);
}
```

Running with 218960 returns...

- [[2,2,2,27370],[2,2,10,5474],[2,2,14,3910],[2,2,34,1610],[2,2,46,1190],[2,2,70,782],[2,2,170,322],[2,2,230,238],[2,2,54740],[2,4,27370],[2,10,14,782],[2,10,34,322],[2,10,46,238],[2,10,10948],[2,14,34,230],[2,14,46,170],[2,14,7820],[2,20,5474],[2,28,3910],[2,34,46,70],[2,34,3220],[2,46,2380],[2,68,1610],[2,70,1564],[2,92,1190],[2,140,782],[2,170,644],[2,230,476],[2,238,460],[2,322,340],[2,109480],[4,10,5474],[4,14,3910],[4,34,1610],[4,46,1190],[4,70,782],[4,170,322],[4,230,238],[4,54740],[8,27370],[10,14,34,46],[10,14,1564],[10,28,782],[10,34,644],[10,46,476],[10,68,322],[10,92,238],[10,21896],[14,20,782],[14,34,460],[14,46,340],[14,68,230],[14,92,170],[14,15640],[20,34,322],[20,46,238],[20,10948],[28,34,230],[28,46,170],[28,7820],[34,46,140],[34,70,92],[34,6440],[40,5474],[46,68,70],[46,4760],[56,3910],[68,3220],[70,3128],[92,2380],[136,1610],[140,1564],[170,1288],[184,1190],[230,952],[238,920],[280,782],[322,680],[340,644],[460,476],[218960]]

...and running with 136 returns...

- [[2,2,34],[2,68],[4,34],[136]]

Comment: What about `[[184, 1190], [8, 27370], [4, 54740], ...]` which are even factorizations of  218960 if I'm understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: @cdlane you understand it correctly, there are some solutions missing. Even though i don't know whether you got them all.
Thats so strange about this problem, you can find nothing on it anywhere, therefore its hard to verify for big numbers.

Comment: @cdlane, I doff my cap at your elegant, and complete, solution!  Yours is the answer that obviously deserves credit.  I have taken the liberty of porting your python solution to javascript, and posted it here for any interested parties.

Comment: I appreciate your port (+1). I've not kept up with the newest features in JavaScript so it's instructive for me while easy to follow since it nicely builds on my solution.